# Room DB is changing order of items when execute get

Tags: java, android, android-room

There is absolutely standard case I save the items in my Room DB

There are 4 items. After I saved it with help of `Stetho` I see that them all were saved in right order 1, 2, 3, 4 like it should be.

Then when I need to get them all

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS")
List<MyObj> getAll(String i,  String iS);
```

I get order like this 1, 2, 4, 3

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not specify that you need them ordered by something

Comment: you could have 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS order by name'

Comment: @Ogbe but I don't need to order by something, I need get items exactly in order that I got from the server side. Of course I can  give the number to all the items, but why? Why I see that in DB it is in right order , but when I try to execute get method I get the items in wrong order?

Comment: "I see that them all were saved in right order 1, 2, 3, 4 like it should be" - these are the inserted primary key id's?

Comment: @MarkKeen no, it is rowid. primary key I use my custom values. But primary key should not affect on order... no?

Comment: The primary key is probably being used for ordering if no order by is provided - you need to use order by in your query, there is no guarantee on ordering otherwise.

Comment: @MarkKeen Hmmm... Ok, is there a way to set `orderedBy : rowid` ??

Comment: `Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS ORDER BY rowid")` - should suffice (assuming rowid being the name in the table you want to order by)

Comment: @MarkKeen no, it doesn't work. Room expecting to get value from the object. As far as I understood I can't say `ORDER BY rowid` , but rowid it is name from table... Hope you understand what I mean..

Comment: is rowid autogenerated?

Comment: @AyejuniIlemobayoKings Yes, but `rowid` is name of colon from DB table . It is not my value

Comment: I think the issue is in the myObj class. how did you create it? did you make all vars public or are they private with getter setter. i would use one or the other. look at your dao_Impl.java file to understand what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that your data will come back in the same order. In SQL, order is not an inherent property of a set of data. And Room is an abstraction on top of SQLite (a SQL db engine). You need to order the data as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify how the ordering should be, it's either you use the primary key/index key e.g if your table entity template is like this

```
@Entity
class Mytable {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   var id: Int? = null
   ...
}
```

you can use this to retrieve and order according as it has been inserted

```
'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS ORDER BY id ASC'
```

or

```
'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :i AND state = :iS ORDER BY id DESC'
```

and from what i see in your code, the reason you have that is the way you query your data, you can shear with me what you plan to archive and some part of your code.

Comment: But I use my custom primaryKey... `@Entity(tableName = "mytable", primaryKeys = {"name", "state"})` . I can't add new primary key, because I have already use one.

Comment: do you have id which is auto generated, if you do use id, do you have any variable with (autoGenerate = true)?

Comment: autoGenerate = true I can use only with `PrimaryKey` , but bacause of I use my custom I can't set it autogenerated...

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and figured out what was going on the hard way.

I wanted to create 2 identical tables so i simply extended an existing class and added the entity annotation to the extended class and for some reason only the schema of the extended entity had one column in the wrong order.

i figured out that this was due to one variable in the entity being declared as public. room was putting this variable at the beginning of my table for some reason. since the order in the schemas of the original and the extended class was different i could not select from one table into the other as i wanted. when i made this variable private everything worked fine and the order matched upon uninstall-install

it just rang a bell when i saw your issue. maybe in your entity class 3 is the only private variable and is therefore relegated to the end